# ui-router resolve is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**Previous questions didn't solve my issue.**

I am trying to send `res.data` in another function and it works. But when I send `res.data[somevalue]` it doesn't work. Basically, my response is an array of objects. I want to send a particular object from the array. Sending the array works.

Service.js

```
getPlayer: function(playerName){
    return $http.get('../data/player.json',{
        cache: true
    }).then(function(res){
        res.data.forEach(function(element) {
            if(element.name == playerName){
                console.log(element);
                return element;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

State

```
    name:'player',
    url:'/players/{playerName}',
    component:'player',
    resolve:{
        player: function(PlayerService, $transition$){
            return PlayerService.getPlayer($transition$.params().playerName);
        }
    }
```

Component

```
angular.module('playerApp').component('player',{
    bindings: {player:'<'},

    template: '<div class="panel panel-success">'+
    '<div class="panel-heading">'+
      '<h3 class="panel-title">Details</h3></div>'+
    '<div class="panel-body"><img height=300 width= 100% src="{{$ctrl.player.image}}">'+
    '<strong>Name:</strong> {{$ctrl.player.name}} </br>'+
    '<strong>Age:</strong> {{$ctrl.player.age}}</br>'+
    '<strong>Country:</strong> {{$ctrl.player.country}}</br>'+
    '<strong>Club:</strong> {{$ctrl.player.club}}</br>'+    
    '</div></div>'
})
```

Comment: Why don't you create a plunker?

Comment: Try changing $transition$.params().playerName to $stateParams.playerName

Comment: @Vivz the parameter is getting passed, no issue there I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the function getPlayers function and it worked.

```
getPlayer: function(playerName){
    return $http.get('../data/player.json',{
        cache: true
    }).then(function(res){
        for(var i in res.data){
            if(res.data[i].name==playerName){
                console.log(res.data[i]);
                return res.data[i];
            }
        }
    });
```